# Affine quadric surfaces

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, linear-groups

I want to understand affine quadric surfaces. What are they? and what are their basic properties? Are they homogeneous spaces?  And which groups act on them? Thanks for your detailed explanation!

Comment: Did you look in "A first course in algebraic geometry" by Harris ? I remember there are lot of example and he spend some time of quadrics (unfortunately my book is at home right now).